# Site-To-Site VPN Failover

Tags: vpn, cisco, routing, internet

Conceptually, how does this work/ would be configured in a Cisco environment, I realise this is quite an open question so please let me narrow it down.

Let's say we have two sites: `SiteA` and `SiteB`, both sites have 2 Internet connections.

```
SiteA has ISP1 and ISP2
SiteB has ISP3 and ISP4
```

At the moment, I have a Site to Site VPN using the Interfaces `ISP1` and `ISP3` respectively at each site.

```
So ISP3 --> ISP1 Site to Site 
   ISP1 --> ISP3 Site to Site
```

However, `ISP1` fails, I need the VPN to failover to `ISP2`. So now ISP3 will see the VPN connection coming from a new IP address. However, if `ISP3` is setup to speak via Site to Site to `ISP1`, which has now gone down, it also needs to move the VPN to start speaking via Site to Site VPN to `ISP2`. How can this even be configured or conceptually understood?

Comment: What types of Cisco devices? Routers? Firewalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IP SLA](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a00806e880b.shtml), have your route to the remote network track an SLA.  When the SLA fails, the route will be removed, which will cause the traffic to go out the other interface.

You will need to build tunnels for both egress interfaces with identical protected traffic but different peers.